# Would one say Kaddish for someone who forfeited his portion in the world to come?

Tags: kaddish, repentance-teshuvah, olam-haba-world-to-come

Inspired by a [recent discussion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34884/kaddish-yatom-what-if-a-parent-really-is-wicked/34885?noredirect=1#comment90424_34885):

Chazal [tell us](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishna_Yoma.8.9) that someone who says "I will sin and I will repent, will not be given the opportunity to repent" (Mishna Yoma 8:9).  Chazal also [tell us](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishna_Sanhedrin.10.1) that there are certain sins for which a person does not have a portion in the World To Come (Mishna Sanhedrin 10:1).

If someone did a sin for which there is no portion in the World To Come, and announced that they were doing it with the intention of repenting later, we can assume that they never repented.  Would there be a point in saying Kaddish for such a person?

Comment: Can you [edit] in why you're asking about _kadish_? I mean, what does _kadish_ have to do with the world to come?

Comment: Some kaabalistic thought says that kaadish helps secure a person's place in the world to come.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if one can generalize but someone who killed himself

- loses his share in the World to Come ([Arukh HaShulchan YD 345:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.345.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
- and one says Kaddish for him.

As R Eliezer Melamed [writes](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-04-05/), based on a Chatam Sofer

> **We even say Kaddish for someone who committed suicide.** Although the
>   Chachamim teach that we do not mourn for him and **he does not have a
>   share in the next life**, the Kaddish that his sons recite for him helps
>   repair his soul slightly

Or as chabad.org [writes](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281618/jewish/Kaddish-Observances.htm)

> Mourners should be encouraged to recite [Kaddish] **for the distinct spiritual
>   benefit of the suicide** who, if the act was intentional, was guilty of
>   a heinous crime. Indeed, it is recommended for this reason, that they
>   recite it for the full year rather than for the customary 11 months.