# Why Kaddish for a parent is said for eleven months?

Tags: calendar, kaddish

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/34883/1362) answer cites a source which explains that Kaddish for a parent is customarily not said for 12 months so as not to imply a parent's status as that of "wicked."

Not wanting to label a parent wicked might justify not filling out the full twelve month period, but it does not explain why, specifically, we stop at 11 months. Is there something independently significant about 11 months that makes it an appropriate minimum time for which to say Kaddish? Couldn't we say it for 11 months and 29 days (or any other time under 12 months)?

Is the soul of the "not wicked" judged for only 11 months giving that time relevance? If the soul is "under divine judgment" for the full time, wouldn't it benefit the soul for us to continue saying Kaddish until right before the label of "wicked" would be applied -- 12 months?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does one say Kaddish for a parent?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11468/how-long-does-one-say-kaddish-for-a-parent)

Comment: You're saying *"Not wanting to label a parent wicked"* is the reason and then you ask why?

Comment: I heard that we have no sources besides speculations for what's really happening in afterdeath. Those are purely Minhagim incl. the Kaddish itself. As the previous answers suggest one can follow any approach.

Comment: I don't see how that other question explains the specific length of 11 months as opposed to any other time less than 12 months.

Comment: As I recall being told that it is because the day before the yahtzeit is considered the end of the year. Ttherefore the equivalent date the previous month is treated as the *early* end of the kadish period. I do not have the source for this, so I am leaving it a comment.